# FileWriter not appending to existing file

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am writing a method that takes in a `List` of Twitter `Status` objects as a parameter, opens a log file containing `String` represenatations of Tweets, checks if any of the `String` representations of the `Status` objects are already written to the file - if so, it removes them from the list, if not it appends the `Status` to the file.

Everything is working up until I attempt to write to the file. Nothing is being written at all. I am led to believe that it is due to the method having the file open in two different places: `new File("tweets.txt")` and `new FileWriter("tweets.txt, true)`.

Here is my method:

```
    private List<Status> removeDuplicates(List<Status> mentions) {
        File mentionsFile = new File("tweets.txt");
        try {
            mentionsFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // Print error + stacktrace
        }

        List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>(); 
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mentionsFile);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileLines.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Print error + stacktrace
        }

        List<Status> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();    
        for (Status mention : mentions) {
            String mentionString = "@" + mention.getUser().getScreenName() + " \"" + mention.getText() + "\" (" + mention.getCreatedAt() + "\")";
            if (fileLines.contains(mentionString)) {
                duplicates.add(mention);
            } else {
                try {
                    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tweets.txt", true));
                    writer.write(mentionString);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Print error + stacktrace
                }

            }
        }

        mentions.removeAll(duplicates);
        return mentions;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote here few thoughts looking your code.

Remember to always close the object `Reader` and `Writer`.

Have a look at [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) :

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tweets.txt", true))) {
   writer.write(mentionString);
} catch (IOException e) {
   // Print error + stacktrace
}
```

To read an entire file in a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("tweets.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And again, I think it's a bad practice write in the same file you're reading of.

I would suggest to write in a different file if you don't have a particular constraint.

But if you really want have this behavior there are few alternative.

1. Create a temporary file as output and, when you process is successfully completed, than move it to the old one using `Files.move(from, to)`.

Comment: To test if that was what was causing the problem, I changed it to `Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tweets2.txt", true));` and it creates `tweets2.txt`, but still doesn't write anything into it.

Comment: you don't flush and close the writer

Comment: So with a `try-with-resources` statement I don't need to explicitly close the resource, it is done automatically? And what about flushing? I presume that still must be done manually?

Comment: No. You flush manually only in particular cases where you want be sure to physically write in a particular moment but normally you don't need to do it.